# How far are the mobile StackExchange apps going to develop?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

I understand that the mobile app allows members to ask and answer questions while not on the laptop, making the site more accessible. But how far is the development expected to go?

For example, the entire activity page is not on the app, nor are the designs for each site. Many aspects of the website are not accessible on the app, but are on the laptop. (or in a browser on the mobile device)

How far are the Stack Exchange engineers planning on going with the app?

Comment: Tag creation, chat, SO Careers, Area 51, and actual working suggested edits are not on the app too. Also, are you talking about iOS or Android or what?

Comment: @Peanut you can't put words into the OP's mouth, your edit was invalid. Since it's already done and wrongly approved, better have both tags, though it makes it too broad.